# mouseX and mouseY only detect diagonal coordinates

Tags: javascript

I am tying the placing of an input box to the mouseX and mouseY coordinates, but my issue is that when I click I can only click in a small diagonal field across the body. I want it so that I can click anywhere on the body and it will go to that location. Any ideas on how to fix this peculiar problem?

```
<body onclick = "getLocation(event)">
    <style>

html{
}
div{
    display: block;
}


 textarea, input {
      clear: both;
position: relative;
}
textarea, input {
overflow: auto;
width: 20%;
}
</style>

<input id = "enter" placeholder = "input" style = "top:20;left:40;"></input>
</body>
<script>
function getLocation(event){
var y = event.clientY;
var x = event.clientY;
console.log("Y:" + y + " X:" + x);
document.getElementById("enter").style.left = x;
document.getElementById("enter").style.top = y;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width and height of the body. You also need to set units on the positions and you most likely want to use pageX and pageY, not clientX and clientY

```js
function getLocation(event){
    var y = event.pageY;
    var x = event.pageX ;
    console.log("Y:" + y + " X:" + x);
    document.getElementById("enter").style.left = x + "px";
    document.getElementById("enter").style.top = y + "px";
  }

document.body.addEventListener("click", getLocation);
```

```css
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
div{
    display: block;
}
textarea, input {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
textarea, input {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<input id="enter" placeholder="input" style="top:20px;left:40px;"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function getLocation(event){

  document.getElementById('enter').style.left  = (window.Event) ? event.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
  document.getElementById('enter').style.top = (window.Event) ? event.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);

}
</script>
```

Just replace this, and it works :)